# Reset Particular Input Element in a HTML Form

Tags: html, forms, reset

I have multiple input textboxes in my page. I want to reset particular text box to its onload state if certain conditions fails. 
   I am considering using a Hidden element to store the onload state of the textbox. I would other suggestions or solutions to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`defaultValue`:

```
<input type="text" value="initial" id="field">
<button id="reset">reset</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('reset').onclick= function() {
        var field= document.getElementById('field');
        field.value= field.defaultValue;
    };
</script>
```

Available on `text`, `password` and `textarea`, plus `defaultChecked` on `checkbox`/`radio` and `defaultSelected` on `option`. Curiously, *not* available on `hidden` (except in IE, where it's considered a bug).