# Reset values in a particular table which are edited on click of Reset button

Tags: javascript, html, reset

On a HTML page I have three sections with 3 tables. Each `table` has its own `Reset` button which should reset only the sections it is required to. Unfortunately, I have used the same form for all the three and there is lot of change to be made if 3 seperate forms are created.

Is there a way to reset only a particular section of the page in this way?

Comment: alternatively if someone can explain how form.reset() works,i think it can be modified only to reset select fields

Comment: Form.reset clears all fields inside the form - You have to make 3 seperate forms if you want to do it with form.reset(). Another solotion is clearing the fields with javascript. Need example?

Comment: I know there is a way clearing each field type by iterating but such reset altogether clears away existing values and not 'modified only' values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`form.reset()` is built in to the browser, so it's behaviour cannot be amended.

An alternative is to write your own code in javascript to reset the fields of each table, like this:

```
function resetInput1(e){
    document.getElementById('input1').value = document.getElementById('input1').defaultValue;
}
function resetInput2(e){
    document.getElementById('input2').value = document.getElementById('input2').defaultValue;
}

document.getElementById("btn1").addEventListener('click', resetInput1, true);
document.getElementById("btn2").addEventListener('click', resetInput2, true);
```

[**Example fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/b55Au/2/)

Comment: I want to reset the field to current value and not to empty.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2689658/reset-particular-input-element-in-a-html-form

Comment: Thanks Rory!!It worked .BTW is {form}.{object}.defaultValue  Cross-browser

Comment: @GustlyWind No problem. It's reliable for cross browser support: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5244466/

Comment: can you give me an example for select-one reset as well in similar lines on fiddle

Comment: I need to reset an existing selected value not to default

Answer (score 1):

here u can write a javascript method to reset all the elements available in your section and call the function on click on the reset button, using form.reset will reset the whole form.

otherwise you can have multiple form on a page and place your reset button inside each and reset.

If you are using .net you cannot have multiple forms on same page. for this you will have to disable/ hide the other forms.

// AFTER YOUR COMMENTS TO MY POST

here u can store the default values in hidden fields means my each element will be having a hidden field, where the default value will be stored.

when a user changes any text in textbox, change index in drop down, unselect some checkboxes, etc, and hits reset button

you will call a javascript function which will set the values from the hidden fields back to the respective controls. This will save your round-trip with the server to fetch the default details back from the database.

otherwise u can use ajax methods to rebind the default values to the element on html form.
I m particularly mentioning Ajax methods here because, if we post back the webpage again it will reset all your values in the other sections.

Hope it is a clear explanation.

Comment: Is this the one you are referring to http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-reset-form.phtml.Actually i need to reset to 'default value' of each of the element

Comment: Default value means, it is a static data on each element, or values retrieved from your database?

Comment: you can just call some ajax method and reset the values back to original on click on reset button and bind the data to each element.

Comment: exactly I want to reset the field to default value and not to empty